# How to add class to link (a tag) while creating custom wordpress toolbar menu?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have specific requirement and that's why I need a class inside `<a href="#">` tag. My problem is I want this inside admin bar menu while creating my custom menu.

I know how to create custom menu inside toolbar. Here is how I am doing it:

```
function admin_bar_custom_menus($wp_admin_bar){
    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'id'     => 'xyz_id',
        'title'  => 'Title',
        'href'   => '#',
        'meta'   => array(
            'class' => 'xyz_class',
        ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'admin_bar_custom_menus', 80 );
```

This works perfect and the new menu shows without any issue. Let me explain again how it outputs:

```
<li id="wp-admin-bar-xyz_id" class="xyz_class">
  <a class="ab-item" href="#">Title</a>
</li>
```

As it added class "ab-item" inside `<a href="#">` tag, I want to add another class here itself inside `<a href="#">` tag to perform something.

I can do it with jQuery, but please let me know if there is any other method which I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can add this code to add class in  tag

For Example I want to add class for post and pages link:

```
add_action( 'admin_init','wpse_60168_custom_menu_class' );
function wpse_60168_custom_menu_class() {
global $menu;
    foreach( $menu as $key => $value ){
        if( 'Posts' == $value[0] )
            $menu[$key][4] .= " custom-class-1";

       if( 'Pages' == $value[0] )
            $menu[$key][4] .= " custom-class-2";
       }
}
```